# In the provided example, what does the prepositional phrase modify?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The film put the spotlight solely **on the eponymous character**.

In this example, is the prepositional phrase (in bold) modifying 'put' like an adverb, or is it acting as an adjectival object complement (describing 'the spotlight')? The way I see it, there are two ways one could look at it, as the prepositional phrase refers to the way the 'film **put** the spotlight', but it also describes how the spotlight is now 'on the eponymous character.'

Comment: I don't really understand how there is a second interpretation.  Yes, the spotlight is now on the eponymous character, but that is because the film placed it there.  The film is the subject of the sentence, so the sentence is about what the film did.

Comment: "***solely** on the eponymous character*" describes "how". "*on the eponymous character*" describes "where". So the answer is "where".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically it is adverbially modifying "put"; it describes *where* the spotlight was put. Semantically, because of the meaning of "put", it also describes the final location of the spotlight.